# Flat locus of finite map between integral schemes is not necessarily open

Tags: algebraic-geometry, flatness, blowup

Let $X,Y$ be integral Noetherian schemes.
Let $f:X\to Y$ be a finite map of schemes. I recently had to show that the set of points $V\subset Y$ over which $f$ is flat is open, as is for instance proven in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682061/flat-morphism-of-finite-type) stackexchange post.

The exercise asked for a counterexample when we drop the finiteness assumption on $f$.
The counterexample I came up with is the following, let $p:Z\to \mathbb{A}^3$ be the blowup of $\mathbb{A}^3$ along $\mathbb{A}^1= V(x,y)$ and let $X= Z\setminus p^{-1}(0)$, then the flat locus of $p:X\to \mathbb{A}^3$ is $D(x,y)\cup V(x,y,z)$ which is not open.

There are two things I dislike about this example

- $X$ is not affine, are there counterexamples where the domain and codomain are affine?
- the map $p:X\to \mathbb{A}^3$ is not surjective.

Are there counterexamples under these additional assumptions?

Comment: This is a little confusing - normally when people talk about the flat locus of a morphism $f:X\to S$, they're talking about the set $\{x\in X\mid \mathcal{O}_X \text{ is flat over } S \text{ at } x\}$. But you're talking about the *image* of this set. Could you [edit] your question to clarify?

Comment: @KReiser, I edited it, I'm not quite talking about the image of this set as the map $f$ might not be surjective, I hope it is clearer like this

Comment: Haha, I guess I misinterpreted it slightly too. Thanks for the clarification.